# how to restrict cells in Excel to take only the from the calender pop up from drop down that I designed

Tags: vba, excel

I made a calendar pop up which appears by right clicking and selecting insert data button. Now, I only want the cells to take date from that calendar.

here is the code.please help

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
On Error Resume Next
Dim NewControl As CommandBarControl
Application.OnKey "+^{C}", "Module1.OpenCalendar"
Application.CommandBars("Cell").Controls("Insert Date").Delete
Set NewControl = Application.CommandBars("Cell").Controls.Add
With NewControl
  .Caption = "Insert Date"
  .OnAction = "Module1.OpenCalendar"
  .BeginGroup = True
  End With
  End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Protecting the sheet (with the cells locked) will prevent alternative methods of inputting the date. If your calendar populates the cell using vba, then protecting the sheet with `UserInterfaceOnly := True` will allow the vba to write to the cell.